# Sql data not displaying in Windows Form ListView using C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am new to coding and have to complete this task as part of a Multi-Layer application. This code runs but the data does not appear in the required ListView. I am not sure what I have done wrong as I have another ListView that uses similar code and works fine. There are only the two columns CategoryID and Category. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Acme.Data_Access_Layer;
using Acme.Business_Layer;

namespace Acme
{ 
    public partial class frmCategoriesView : Form
    {
        public frmCategoriesView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DisplayCategories()
        {
            string selectQuery = "SELECT Categories.CategoryID, Categories.Category FROM Categories ";
            SqlConnection conn = ConnectionManager.DatabaseConnection();
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    //Define the list items

                    Categories categories = new Categories(int.Parse(rdr["CategoryID"].ToString()), rdr["Category"].ToString());

                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(categories.CategoryID.ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(categories.Category);
                    lvCategory.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
                if (rdr != null)
                    rdr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unsuccessful" + ex);
            }
        }

        private void frmCategoriesView_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            frmMainForm mainForm = new frmMainForm();
            mainForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void frmCategoriesView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayCategories();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger to see what the reader returns? Did you set the listview to View=Details mode?

Comment: This is the only msg that comes back within the output from debug that does not pass the debug:                      'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.   The Listview Vies is set to Details.

Comment: _Cannot find or open the PDB file_ Hm, do you know what that file is? Can you even open the connection?

Comment: Connection works and I am able to view data from another table "Customers" but for some reason, the Categories data does not appear in Listview.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
"SELECT Categories.CategoryID, Categories.Category FROM Categories ";
```

to

```
"SELECT CategoryID, Category FROM Categories ";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it the data is still not appearing in the ListView.

Comment: @JulieM Try that you can get the data, Try put them in DataGridView or something else to be sure your connection true and you can got the data.

Comment: Thanks Nano, I have done that already and it worked fine. Unfortunately, though the requirements of the task have to be a Listview.

Comment: @JulieM I know this small problems could make us so angry because they are so easy  and  make us losing much time .. if you like, upload your project somewhere or send it via email so we can have better look on it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the Load Event. I ended up deleting the event code, ensuring that it was cleared in properties and then redid the event and it worked.